# YouTube Data/ Player API Jquery Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, youtube

I'm having trouble getting YouTube video id's to be parsed to a function that plays them in an embedded player. I am using Javascript / JQuery combination with the YouTube Data and Player APIs. Here is my code below:

```
<html>

<head>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script> 



    <script type="text/javascript">

    //LOAD YOUTUBE PLAYER       
    var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
    var atts = { id: "myytplayer" };
    swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/e/nDq9o9j3-CU?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer",
                   "ytapiplayer", "425", "356", "8", null, null, params, atts);


    //ALLOW CALLS TO BE MADE TO YOUTUBE PLAYER
    function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
    ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
    };                     


    //PLAY A VIDEO BY THE GIVEN VIDEO ID (PARSED FROM THE JSON OUTPUT)
    function play(vid) {
        if (ytplayer) {
            ytplayer.loadVideoById(vid);
        }
    }




    //GETTING THE JQUERY GOING
    $(document).ready(function(){



        //JSON URL FOR THE VIDEOS I AM TARGETTING
        var url = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=TedxConejo&orderby=published&max-results=50&v=2&alt=jsonc";

        //PULL THE JSON OUTPUT FROM THAT URL AND PUT IT INTO A FUNCTION
        $.getJSON(url,
            function(response){

                //LOOP THROUGH EACH ITEM IN THE OUTPUT
                $.each(response.data.items, function(i,video){
                    //CREATE A THUMBNAIL WITH A LINK FOR EACH ITEM
                    $("#jsonOutput").append("<a href='#' name="+video.id+"><img style='width:100px' src='" + video.thumbnail.hqDefault + "'/></a>")
                });

        });


    //FUNCTION TO FIRE WHEN THUMBNAILS ARE CLICKED
    $("a").click(function(){
        //GRAB VIDEO ID FROM NAME ATTRIBUTE OF LINK
        $(this).attr("name") = video_id;    



        //PARSE VIDEO ID TO PLAY FUNCTION
            play(video_id);

        });


        });

        </script>





    </head>


    <body>

    <h1>Hello, World</h1>

  <div id="jsonOutput" style="width:800px; float:left; margin-right:20px"></div>
  <div id="ytapiplayer">
  </div>



    </body>
</html>
```

No bugs or errors occur, and nothing seems to be happening. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Elliott

Answer (score 0):

From Google Chromeless API:

Note: To test any of these calls, you must have your file running on a webserver, as the Flash player restricts calls between local files and the internet. [1]

Why don't you try on-line demo? [2]

[1] http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#GettingStarted

[2] http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/youtube_player_demo.html?playerType=chromeless&playerVersion=as3